# ASUS zenfone5 t00j AES 256 decryption issue

Tags: javascript, android, encryption, cryptojs, badpaddingexception

I am working on mobile application and client side we are using JavaScript (kony)  at server side its java. This is working fine for all other device except intel chipset devices (ASUS Zenfone). PFB the JS code for encryption

```
function encryptDataModeCBC() 
{
    var encData = "Test";
    try 
    {
        var encText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encData, "3f4c57006f7d2d9528de3c46b626df06cdc405cb0243b10ca7612d967c688744", {
            iv: "31fd1ae51454cd55db81f1fa60a343ed",
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 
        alert ("encText => "+encText);    
        kony.print("$$$$ encText => "+encText);    
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        alert(kony.i18n.getLocalizedString("technicalError"));      
    }
}
```

Here creating IV & secret key using sha256 & sha512 hashing algorithm.

PFB the code snippet which we are using at server side for decrypting the encrypted string

secret key generation code

```
private SecretKeySpec getKey(String mode, String msgDigest, String encryptionKey, boolean is256) throws Exception {
    byte[] key = encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance(msgDigest); // This is SHA-256
    key = sha.digest(key);
    if (is256) {  // This is true in our case.
      key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);
      this.logger.debug("Secret Key " + DigestUtils.sha256Hex(encryptionKey).substring(0, 32));
    } else {
      key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
      this.logger.debug("Secret Key " + DigestUtils.sha256Hex(encryptionKey).substring(0, 16));
    }
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    String modeStr = mode.equals("ECB") ? "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" : "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(modeStr);
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

IV generation at server side

```
private IvParameterSpec getIV(String uid, String pin) throws Exception {
  String ivValue = new StringBuilder(uid).reverse().toString() + new StringBuilder(pin).reverse();
  byte[] key = ivValue.getBytes("UTF-8");
  MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
  key = sha.digest(key);
  key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
  IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(key);
  return iv;
}
```

As I mentioned above this is failing in intel chipset devices. This is the exception which I am getting while decrypting the string

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

When I tried encrypting the string "Test" I am getting "Tn2SzI8dmgCmEvQrzdqLxw==" as encrypted string which I have used in below java code and tried to decrypt where I am getting the below error

```
enc text => 7b9UNDI4IWNITNAQlYNP8w==
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at com.ust.Encryptor.decrypt(Encryptor.java:92)
at com.ust.Encryptor.main(Encryptor.java:113)
```

Here is the JAVA code which I have used for decrypting

```
package com.ust;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;    
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class Encryptor {
    private static final String AES_PASS = "0ca763dc6b05b5230e44beb6b90e346440204b6d334b09623eafd3fcfbad6a302faca28b0994872e3fd782e7353026684b7ac9385662144e0ed1e2a8e3e14fab79059929681e3794eb97271328ecccda6dbfb3a7991ea1324615cf5908fabdf6"; // Hashed into an AES key later
    private SecretKeySpec keyObj;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private IvParameterSpec ivObj;
    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();


    public Encryptor() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        // A constant IV, since CBC requires an IV but we don't really need one

        String ivValue = new StringBuilder("astring").reverse().toString() + new StringBuilder("0ca763dc6b05b5230e44beb6b90e346440204b6d334b09623eafd3fcfbad6a302faca28b0994872e3fd782e7353026684b7ac9385662144e0ed1e2a8e3e14fab").reverse();
        System.out.println("ivValue => "+ivValue);
        try {
            byte[] ivkey = ivValue.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest shaIv = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            ivkey = shaIv.digest(ivkey);
            ivkey = Arrays.copyOf(ivkey, 16);
            System.out.println("IV => "+bytesToHex(ivkey));
            this.ivObj = new IvParameterSpec(ivkey);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create an SHA-256 256-bit hash of the key
        byte[] key = AES_PASS.getBytes();
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32); // Use only first 256 bit
        System.out.println("SEC KEY => "+bytesToHex(key));
        this.keyObj = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        // Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters
        //  a. Algorithm name - here it is AES 
        //  b. Mode - here it is CBC mode 
        //  c. Padding - e.g. PKCS7 or PKCS5
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    }

    public String encrypt(String strDataToEncrypt) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String strCipherText = new String();

        this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.keyObj, this.ivObj);

        // Encrypt the Data 
        //  a. Declare / Initialize the Data. Here the data is of type String 
        //  b. Convert the Input Text to Bytes 
        //  c. Encrypt the bytes using doFinal method
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();

        byte[] byteCipherText = this.cipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);

        // b64 is done differently on Android
        strCipherText = Base64.encodeBase64String(byteCipherText);

        return strCipherText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String strCipherText) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String strDecryptedText = new String();

        // Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
        this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.keyObj, this.ivObj);

        // Decode the Base64 text
        byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(strCipherText);

        // Decrypt the Data
        //  a. Initialize a new instance of Cipher for Decryption (normally don't reuse the same object)
        //     Be sure to obtain the same IV bytes for CBC mode.
        //  b. Decrypt the cipher bytes using doFinal method
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = this.cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);

        return strDecryptedText;
    }
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException{
        Encryptor aesCipher = new Encryptor();
        try {
            String encText = aesCipher.encrypt("Test");
            System.out.println("enc text => "+encText);
            String plaintext = aesCipher.decrypt("Tn2SzI8dmgCmEvQrzdqLxw==");//("eat6f1uCCXVqJgTNUA8BCqXSA4kG4GhKajXdkyV0TewK+jgDkbQ/lPVaevv4rW3XdSmtVyOKLVJjPw9Akeblrh+ejIv9u48n7PkRKniwfxq/URuPU7lhS/sO5JMiJ7+ufgKFvJapxhSfftCtigtDc8F6Y2lJIPEUeQeQKOVc1noeLqPFggz55hWjWvDtpYh/sG76MwLlWDM7cj+uu6ru3ImmDA7qoM4tJOWBBkfng8u20R1ZcF3gM45TgDLUdL912AE1WO+grGBGjqzTXlK2/jgu3OOsLVI0jndB49K5q3/oKJc7JEoIZb0eZJcuZ80A");
            System.out.println("plain text => "+plaintext);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Artjom, I have updated the post with sample codes which I have used to reproduce the issue. can you please help me to understand why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CryptoJS assumes that

- a key which is passed as a string is actually a password and will hash it again along with a randomly generated salt or it will use the key as-is if it is a WordArray and
- the IV should be a WordArray

WordArray is CryptoJS' internal binary data representation.

The code should be:

```
try {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("3f4c57006f7d2d9528de3c46b626df06cdc405cb0243b10ca7612d967c688744");
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("31fd1ae51454cd55db81f1fa60a343ed44");
    var encText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encData, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 
    alert ("encText => "+encText);    
    kony.print("$$$$ encText => "+encText);    
} 
catch (e) 
{
    alert(kony.i18n.getLocalizedString("technicalError"));
}
```

---

Something to think about:

- If you send the symmetric key from the server to the client, then anyone who might be listening will get the key and can decrypt the ciphertexts you send. This solution doesn't provide security, but rather obfuscation. You should use TLS which would make the connection actually secure.
- The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.
- It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Artjom, the Key & iv which I have passed as string are already doing a cryptoJS.enc.hex. for testing purpose only I have hard coded the value.

Comment: when i tried with above code i am getting encText as null.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `CryptJS.enc.Hex.parse` instead of `CryptJS.enc.Hex`. I get the ciphertext 7b9UNDI4IWNITNAQlYNP8w==

Comment: Thank you very much Artjom. you saved my day. it is working like charm. I have tested this in android emulator. need to test it in Asus zenfone5 t00j.where I was facing this issue. thanks a lot once again

Comment: thanks for the suggestion also. we are using TLS 1.2 protocol and using only dynamic key and iv.

Comment: i have tested the same code in ASUS zenfone (intel chipset) but here i am getting different encrypted string for "Test" data.

Comment: This must be a bug in CryptoJS. Have you tried [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)?